# Giving IIS access to files shared from a mac

Tags: virtual-machines, network-share, mac, iis-10

I'm relatively new when it comes to network administration, but I have put in many hours of research and effort before asking this question. I know my question is similar to many others, but I don't believe it is a duplicate. My apologies if I'm mistaken.

**Basic setup/problem:**

I'm trying to run a PHP/Codeigniter website with IIS on a Windows virtual machine, but with the source code shared from the host (which is a mac). I'm getting the following IIS error when I try to load the home page:

**Details on error:**

- 500.19 - The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid
- Config Error - Cannot read configuration file (web.config)
- Error code - 0x8007010b

According to this page, "This problem can occur if the specified content directory cannot be accessed." https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942055/http-error-500-19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage

**The crux:**

So apparently I haven't successfully given IIS permission to the files on the mac side.

**Some details:**

- The host is a macbook running Catalina 10.15.
- The host is sharing files via System Preferences -> Sharing.
- With VirtualBox 6.0.14, I'm running a guest OS, which is Windows v1909.
- The vm is attached to Bridged Adapter.
- IIS version is 10.0.18362.1
- The web.config file is already there, and it runs fine on other deployments of this site (that aren't trying to used shared files), so it's fine.

**Here are things I have in place, which I've learned from many similar questions:**

- The mac user I'm using has "Read & Write" access. I can access, edit, and save the shared files in Explorer on the Windows VM.
- The windows user I'm using has the exact same name and password as the mac user
- The windows user is an admin
- The Application Pool is configured to use that Windows user as the Identity (under Process Model)
- The site's Authentication is set to use that Application Pool identity
- In IIS -> the website -> Basic Settings -> "Test Settings...", Authentication and Authorization are both passing the test. It says, "The specified user credentials are valid."
- The URL Rewrite extension for IIS is installed
- No impersonation flag is set in php.ini.

As mentioned above, the site I'm trying to run is built on PHP/Codeigniter. That's where I'm getting the error. However, if I change the "Basic settings" of the website to point to a simple html file shared from the mac, it displays just fine. So I suspect the error may have something to do with php, or with something more sophisticated than just displaying an html file.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: "The host is sharing files via System Preferences -> Sharing" is doomed to fail, as you can find tons of similar posts over the internet. You have to use other alternatives to copy files between Windows and Mac, which won't mess up file permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, Lex. I started off using VirtualBox's shared folder feature and then retreated to this approach. Can you recommend any specific file sharing methods that would work?